# Missing dependency with Swagger configured in Java

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, swagger

I'm trying to launch our API server using Swagger. We don't use a web.xml at all, and instead configure everything in Java. I'm attempting to follow the instructions from [the Swagger JAX-RS tutorial](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/java-jax-rs), but still having problems. I'm using the latest code from Git (locally-installed 1.2.1-SNAPSHOT)

```java
final Server jetty = injector.getInstance(Server.class);

ServletContextHandler sch = injector.getInstance(ServletContextHandler.class);
sch.setInitParameter("swagger.api.basepath", "http://localhost:8090");
sch.setInitParameter("api.version", "0.1");

JuiceContainer unprotected = new JuiceContainer(injector, ApiListingResource.class);
sch.addFilter(new FilterHolder(unprotected), "/*", null);
sch.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");
```

And the ApiListingResource is exactly how suggested in the tutorial:

```java
@Path("/resources.json")
@Api("/resources")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ApiListingResource extends JavaApiListing { }
```

Unfortunately, when launching the server I get this error:

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.JavaApiListing.getAllApis(javax.servlet.ServletConfig,javax.ws.rs.core.Application,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.JavaApiListing.getAllApis(javax.servlet.ServletConfig,javax.ws.rs.core.Application,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo), annotated with GET of resource, class com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.JavaApiListing, is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

Comment: Are you using Grizzly2?  This seems to be a known issue with Jersey and Grizzly2, see http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1047.  There was a pull request for Swagger which supposedly fixed (or worked around) the issue but the changes it made were reversed by a later pull request (https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/pull/64).  I "fixed" the issue by switching to using Jetty instead of Grizzly2

Comment: It works fine when using a servlet instead of a filter - see https://www.bountysource.com/issues/38004856-jersey1-19-swagger-have-a-exception-for-com-sun-jersey-spi-inject-errors-errormessagesexception-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this myself in Swagger; there is a [pull request](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/pull/151) open right now.